# Can you please rename the htmlagilitypack tag to html-agility-pack?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

[htmlagilitypack](/questions/tagged/htmlagilitypack) should probably be renamed to [html-agility-pack](/questions/tagged/html-agility-pack).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and did this even though no one has commented on it yet since it's an easily reversible change (in the event that someone comes up with a really good reason it should be the other way around).